# Replace every even number in Pascal's triangle with an asterisk?

Tags: c, pascals-triangle

I'm trying to replace every even number in Pascal's triangle with an asterisk (*). So far, my code is looking like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
long calc( int );
int main()
{
 int i,j,row,pas;
 printf("Enter no. of rows in pascal triangle : ");
 scanf("%d", &row);
 for(i=0; i<row; i++)
 {
   for(j=0; j<=(row-i-1); j++)
     printf(" ");
   for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
   {
     pas=calc(i)/(calc(j)*calc(i-j));
     printf("%ld ",pas); 
   }
   printf("\n");
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

long calc( int num)
{
 int x;
 long res=1;
 for(x=1; x<=num; x++)
   res=res*x;
 return (res);
}
```

I need to insert this block of code (maybe?)

```
if (i%2==0)
{
    i = asterisk;
    printf("%c", asterisk);
}
```

Of course I will put in main ()

```
char asterisk = 42;
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried this? Hint: why ever would you *modify* `i`?

Comment: My bad, I was doing something else at that time, and I forgot to remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/qIN4Sf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char asterisk = 42;
long calc( int );
int main()
{
 int i,j,row,pas;
 printf("Enter no. of rows in pascal triangle : ");
 scanf("%d", &row);
 printf("\n");
 for(i=0; i<row; i++)
 {
   for(j=0; j<=(row-i-1); j++)
     printf(" ");
   for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
   {
     pas=calc(i)/(calc(j)*calc(i-j));
     if (pas%2==0)
        printf("%c ", asterisk);
     else
        printf("%ld ",pas); 
   }
   printf("\n");
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

long calc( int num)
{
 int x;
 long res=1;
 for(x=1; x<=num; x++)
   res=res*x;
 return (res);
}
```

Comment: No problem I added a `printf("\n");` after the `scanf` so the first value looks better